# Excel VBA need macro to to find matching values and copy row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets - Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Both Sheets contain a column named IDNumber that contains a unique customer ID number.  Sheet1 has customer order history, and Sheet2 has the customer mailing address.  Sheet1 has multiple instances of a single customer (one row for each individual order they placed).  I need to loop through the sheets, and check the IDNumber from Sheet1 against the IDNumber in Sheet2, and then copy the row from Sheet2 (mailing address) into Sheet1 in columns E - J.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.  There are literally **hundreds** of questions identical in scope to this one, here on Stack Overflow. Find one, try to modify it for your specific needs, and if you have **specific** problems, we'll be happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: You can do a search for [excel] find copy and return 1254 results [Find Copy Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel]+find+copy). Results include past questions like: [Compare data in two columns and then copy range of cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521361/compare-data-in-two-columns-and-then-copy-range-of-cells) , [Copying relative cell to another worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320352/excel-vba-macro-copying-relative-cell-to-another-worksheet) , [Find and copy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947365/find-and-copy-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the mailing address is in columns B-G on sheet 2.

In sheet 1, column E, use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$G,2,FALSE)
```

Then copy over and down. No VBA required. You may need to edit the formula to reflect your situation (e.g. renamed Sheet2)

Comment: You are correct in your assumption.  I'm getting #N/A when I paste that in to Column E.  My IDNumber in Sheet1 is in Column D.  I'm unclear on how the VLOOKUP function works.

Comment: @BrianStanley The first parameter ($A2) refers to the column on sheet1 to look for. Change that to $D2 and see if it works. Also: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: I had to change it to use Column D - VLOOKUP($D2,Sheet2!$A:$G,2,FALSE).  It wouldn't let me copy and paste it to where it would change the formula for me.  I just changed the Column value to match each Column. This worked.  Thank you much, Jack!